# Convert CHM file to WinHelp (.HLP)

Tags: windows, chm, winhelp

This may seem like an odd request, but I'd like to know a way to convert a .chm file to .hlp. Is that at all possible? If so, is there any method I can follow or software I can use to achieve that?

Comment: I'd not recommend this way of migrating to an old help file format. The newer but about 25 years old CHM help file format is deprecated too and HTMLHelp Workshop was dropped by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are automatic converters for this.

There are CHM decompiler tools, should not be hard to find. This will give you a bunch of HTML files and perhaps some topic/index files. Even the official Microsoft HTML help workshop can help you with this.

To create a .hlp you need to (manually?) convert the HTML files to .rtf if you want to use the official Microsoft compiler. You can probably find it in older SDKs or [here](https://download.jgsoft.com/helpscribble/HC.zip) or [there](https://www.pcorner.com/list/WINDOWS/HC505.ZIP/INFO/).

You have to ask yourself, is there any point in doing this? The .hlp format is no longer supported and Windows has not included a viewer for a long time.

If the help file belongs to an application instead of a generic manual or book then there are other things you need to deal with, a different API in the application and you need to port over all topics so they retain their correct id etc. If the HTML included Javascript then you might have a hard time porting those features.

If you are looking for a generic tool, [Halibut](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/halibut/#) can generate HLP, CHM and PDF from the same source files. Requires its own input format though.